# is it possible to check what the client is sending to the server using java

Tags: java

I am writing a client server based java program. I have two queries I was hoping someone will be able to answer.
First query, Is there a way to check what the client has sent to the server?
Second query is, is there code that will allow the server to check the file they have received from the client? I have been unable to find answers to this online

this is my server code

```
package servers;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Servers {

public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception
{
    try 
    {
        // server variable
        ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(9999);
        Socket client=server.accept();


        BufferedReader fromClient=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String temp=fromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println("Recieved files");
        server.close();


   while ((temp = fromClient.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
}
}
```

this is my client code

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{

public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception
{   
    try 
    {
       File file=new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\College 2013\\FYP\\Attribute Data\\Alex.txt"); 
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }


    Socket socket=new Socket("Localhost", 9999);
    PrintWriter toServer=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader fromServer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String toSend,rec="";

       if(!file.exists())
{
    System.out.println("File not found terminating program.");

} 

br.close();
toServer.println("this is the end");
System.out.println("Finished sending file.");
System.out.println("Begining to receive Server output.");


 while (!(rec = fromServer.readLine()).equals("this is the end"))
{
    System.out.println(rec);
}

toServer.close();
br.close();
socket.close();

return;
} 
catch (Exception e) 
    {

    } 
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use a [sha1sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum) on both sides (there is a Java API for it so don't use an external program). Client sends file, then sends sha1sum. Server receives file, calculates sha1sum, then calculates sha1sum itself on the file only. If the sums match, all good. If they don't match, either the sha1sum transferred from the client, or the file data itself, doesn't match, and in any case you need to re-run the transfer because there was a problem. Usually if you're doing this over TCP you won't have random data corruption, but the received file could be truncated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope you can help me out again I have never used sha1sum before how do you implement it?

Comment: This should be on stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you send me the path to it on stack overflow if you know where it is i couldnt find it ?

Comment: You need to learn to be self-sufficient. Don't ask me (or anyone, for that matter) to spoon-feed you. Use a search engine. Google "sha1 java api". Read the JavaDocs. Being able to help yourself solve problems independently and learn in a self-directed manner will improve your career and academic success 100,000 times more than me teaching you how to use the Java SHA1 API. And don't just look for code examples; learn how to interpret documentation and translate it into code. You need to understand what you're looking at, and if you don't, obtain the knowledge you need by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a program such as `tcpdump`  or `wireshark` to watch the network traffic going back and forth. I usually use `tcpdump` from a command line; however, `wireshark` has a GUI and maybe some people like that better.

I think it is better to use a separate program to watch the traffic. That way you don't have to complicate your program with extra stuff, and also the external program can be applied to anything that generates network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You could also setup an intercepting proxy such as [OWASP Hatkit Proxy Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Hatkit_Proxy_Project)

Answer (score 0):

tcptrace works quite well, is very small, for Windows only
http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/